# create button for link_to in html erb for email

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email

I am generating an email from a html.erb file in my rails application for the user to confirm their email address. I am trying to make the link_to line below a green button just like I use in other emails. However it shows up as a plain text link.

This is the link I am having trouble with

```
      <tr style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; margin: 0;">
      <td class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: top; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px;" valign="top">
          <%= link_to 'Confirm Email', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token), class: 'btn-sm-mpgreen' %>
      </td>
      </tr>
```

And it looks like this in the email

[image]

This is the green button from another email I create that I want to use above also.

```
                    <a href="<%= ENV['EXTERNAL_URL'] %>/#/new_match" class="btn-primary" itemprop="url" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2em; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #13904B; margin: 10px 0; border-color: #13904B; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;">Schedule Match</a>
```

Which looks like this in the email

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add styling to your class

```
.btn-sm-mpgreen {
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; 
 font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2em;
 font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #13904B; margin: 10px 0; 
 border-color: #13904B; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the above code to the head of the html.erb file and it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't added styles to your `html.erb` where you are designing your email. Write in `head` something like:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Rails Email</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .background { background-color:#555555; height:2px; }
  /* Some of your css code */
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: I tried adding the code below to the head of the html.erb file and it did not make any difference.  `.btn-sm-mpgreen {
 font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; 
 font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2em;
 font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #13904B; margin: 10px 0; 
 border-color: #13904B; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px 20px;
}`

Comment: @calilonghorn Hm, do you have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` set ?

Comment: [Aleks] Yes I have that set.